# changing Mumamo custom face settings in emacs

Tags: emacs23

I am using nXhtml, flymake and the solarized color theme in emacs 23. 
Everything works fine but I am not particularly happy with the colors that are being used for displaying constants in php. Bright red and doesn't go well with the solarized dark theme and flymake errors. (see attached image)!
[image]

Although I have changed the flymake errline background to underline now but still the constants look ugly on their own.

I have tried customizing Mumamo but dont quite understand what exactly to change.

Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you failed your image attachment

Comment: oh. I can see it here. may be browser issue ? I am using chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience with the modes you mentioned, however, it does not seem like mumamo is the right place to go looking. That mode merely divides up a buffer in to particular mode-ed regions. I think you probably want to go after customizing solarized. I am not sure where you got that, but I found one [here](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized/blob/master/solarized-definitions.el). Looking at that file, solarized-definitions.el, which is part of that solarized package, I see lines like this:

```
     '((base03  "#002b36" "#042028" "#1c1c1c" "#7f7f7f")
      (base02  "#073642" "#0a2832" "#262626" "#000000") ...
```

These do not seem to be set up to be customizable, so you may have to edit the code to change them. If you look further down in the file, you see code like this:

```
     (font-lock-builtin-face ((t (:foreground ,green))))
     (font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground ,base01 :slant ,italic))))
     (font-lock-constant-face ((t (:foreground ,cyan))))
```

These are assigning the color values to particular syntactically-significant font-lock faces. This is another location where changes could be made but they are limited to the palatte of colors defined earlier.

If you have solarized coming from another place, please let us know where.